# Python Django AttributeError 'str' object has no attribute 'user_name'

Tags: python, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

Iam using 'Django Rest Framework' and I am trying to use HyperlinkedModelSerializer, and SlugRelatedField, i have some errors.
When i try use http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/, i get error like:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'trela'

models:

```
class User(models.Model):
    id_user = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    age = models.IntegerField(null=False)
```

views:

```
class UserList(APIView):

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        modele = User.objects.all()
        serializer_class = UserSerializer(modele, many=True)
        return Response(serializer_class.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer_class = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer_class.is_valid():
            serializer_class.save()
            return Response(serializer_class.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer_class.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class UserDetail(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        content = {
            'status': 'Musisz być zalogowany'
        }
        return Response(content)

    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
        modele = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer_class = UserSerializer(modele)
        return Response(serializer_class.data)

    def put(self, request, pk, format=None):
        modele = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer_class = UserSerializer(modele, data=request.data)
        if serializer_class.is_valid():
            serializer_class.save()
            return Response(serializer_class.data)
        return Response(serializer_class.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
        modele = self.get_object(pk)
        modele.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

serializers:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    user_name = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        read_only=True,
        slug_field='trela'
    )
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id_user', 'user_name', 'password', 'email', 'age']
```

traceback:
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6emR.png)

Comment: Can you include the entire traceback?

Comment: @Ihar your sadly did't work, The field '(user name i was created)' was declared on serializer UserSerializer, but has not been included in the 'fields' option.

Comment: @C.Nivs  I added traceback image

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.